# In Elasticsearch, How to distinguish between, Apple Inc. vs apple ( fruit )

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

What would need to do, to made/create/differentiate between, while searching the word "*apple*" over ***Apple Inc***. vs ***apple ( fruit )***

for example, search query like below at dataset where both Apple Inc. and apple as fruit are present :

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field" :  "apple"
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
GET my_index/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "field" :  "apple"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is being called **[Natural Language Processing (NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)** and it is not available out of the box. But the following articles should lead you in the right direction:

- https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-classification-made-easy-with-elasticsearch
- https://www.google.com/search?q=elasticsearch+NLP
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ZF3IYNTzQ

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [boosting query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-boosting-query.html)  with negative boost with word `inc` can do the trick. This solution doesn't eliminate all the document with the word `Apple Inc` but this solution put the document with the word `apple` on top and the document with the word `Apple inc` after.